# Redshift connection in terraform create composer module

Tags: airflow, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to find a module in terraform where we can create a composer env with red shift and aws conn .. I am able to create a compser with pypi packages but need to also add the connection as we can do it from airflow ui

Any examples of aws and redshift conn are appreciated